# How specified a pattern in NLTK regexp tokenizer to work wit numbers?

Tags: python, nltk

I wrote the following code to handle decimal number and remove punctuations.But It does not return the output that I expected. Could you please tell my the errors in  the regular expression.

```
def preprocess(sentence):
sentence = sentence.lower()
pattern=pattern = r'''(?x)               # set flag to allow verbose regexps
          ([A-Z]\.)+         # abbreviations, e.g. U.S.A.
          | \$?\d+(,|.\d+)*
          | \$?\d+%?
          | \w+([-'/]\w+)*    # words w/ optional internal hyphens/apostrophe
          |/\m+([-'/]\w+)*
        '''

tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer(pattern)
tokens = tokenizer.tokenize(sentence)
stopWords = set(stopwords.words('english'))
filtered_words = [w for w in tokens if not w in stopWords]
print filtered_words


sentence = "At eight o'clock@yahoo.com /m/098yh6 baby??? sun'problems 67% on Thu_rsday 76,564 morning: Arthur; didn't 34.56 feel very good. French-Fries"
print preprocess(sentence)
```

output:

> ['eight', "o'clock", 'yahoo', 'com', '/m/098yh6', 'baby', "sun'problems", **'67'**, 'thu_rsday', **'76,564'**, 'morning', 'arthur', "didn't", **'34.56'**, 'feel', 'good', 'french-fries']

My problem is that it remove % from 67. when I change the order these two lines

```
| \$?\d+%?                
| \$?\d+(,|.\d+)*
```

the output is changed to the following lines:

> ['eight', "o'clock", 'yahoo', 'com', '/m/098yh6', 'baby', "sun'problems", **'67%'**, 'thu_rsday', **'76', '564',** 'morning', 'arthur', "didn't", **'34', '56'**, 'feel', 'good', 'french-fries']

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: How about `\$?\d+(?:,\d+)*(?:\.\d+)?%?`

Comment: @DYZ it  works. Thank you. Could you please explain it a little bit.

Comment: It's digits, optionally followed by comma-digits (the thousands  separator), optionally followed by period-digits (the decimal part), optionally followed by %. In fact, if you want to be true to the "thousands" in "thousands separator", it has to be `\$?\d{1-3}(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d+)?%?`.